# Why we are using client.flush() in the program code ,when we connect Esp8266 with internet or web server?

Tags: serial, esp8266, wifi, web-server

I am using Esp8266 Wifi modular (12-E) for controlling a led through the access of wifi/webserver.
I have written code in Arduino ide taking various references from the google.In the code, I didn't understand the client.flush(), why we are using this method? In google, I have searched about many explanations, I got common to explain which I don't understand till yet.
**"Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete."**
I didn't get till yet. can anyone explain to me in simple terms?

/

```
/ Wait until the client sends some data

  Serial.println("new client");

  while(!client.available()){

    delay(1);

  }

  // Read the first line of the request

  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');

  Serial.println(request);

  client.flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely related to the *old* usage of `.flush()` from pre IDE version 1.0.0.

In those old versions `.flush()` would erase any pending data in the reception buffer. It was the equivalent of:

```
while (client.available()) {
    client.read();
}
```

Now though it's used to ensure that all data has been sent before doing anything else. In this situation it's completely meaningless.

Comment: I mean to say suppose if I am client, request for anything from the server and my request read by in the Arduino by this line "
String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');"
Then the serial monitor will print my message.
then client. flush will flush my current request before coming to a new client request. Is it?
please give me a simple example where I can understand easily. if possible try to explain to me from the code which is posted above.

Comment: With a version of the IDE released within the past few years `client.flush()` will do absolutely nothing. In an ancient  version it would discard anything remaining in the buffer.

Comment: **In those old versions .flush() would erase any pending data in the reception buffer. It was the equivalent of** can you explain to me what is meaning of reception buffer? is it a place where incoming data will store?

Comment: Yes. It's where your "client" stores the data it receives *before* you `.read()` it.

Comment: **With a version of the IDE released within the past few years client.flush() will do absolutely nothing. In an ancient version, it would discard anything remaining in the buffer.** sir I need toa ask you what is buffer?

Comment: **Yes. It's where your "client" stores the data it receives before you .read() it.** Sir,  can you explain to me, in brief, the above code which I have posted earlier?

Comment: A client never knows when it's going to receive data. Data just arrives. When it does so an interrupt (typically) is triggered. This interrupt receives the data that has arrived and stores it away in an internal block of memory called a "buffer". Your code then uses `.read()` to get the data out of that "buffer". Data can arrive and be stored into that buffer at any time, not just when you're using `.read()` to get it into your program. If more data is sent (and thus stored in the buffer) than you read from it with `.read()` then there will be data left over. `.flush()` used to remove ...

Comment: ... that data from the buffer, but now doesn't. Now if you want to empty out any remaining data you have to do it manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113425/discussion-between-arijeet-roy-and-majenko).